# Is it possible to split cells with line breaks into multiple rows in a range?

Tags: vba, excel, line-breaks

I have a range of data , where some of the cells have line breaks, and I need to split the line breaks into rows below where the line break occurs, but leave the other cells as is. There are also multiple columns if that makes a difference.

I have used the two answers provided below, with some adjustments to fit my worksheet, but neither is working for splitting ALL the cells. I ended up even trying both, but that does not work either.

When there is a line break in column A, it is working, but when there is not a line break in column A, and there is in another column, it does not work. If there is NOT a line break in column A, I just need to split the row where there is a line break and merge it into the row below.

Here are the codes:

```
end_row = range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row

range("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=range("a1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, OtherChar _
    :="   ", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

For i = 1 To end_row
    row_added = False
    For j = 1 To 4
        If InStr(1, Cell, Chr(10)) <> 0 Then
            If Not row_added Then
                Rows(i + 1).Insert
                row_added = True
                end_row = end_row + 1
            End If
            Cells(i + 1, j) = Right(Cells(i, j), Len(Cells(i, j)) - InStr(1, Cell, Chr(10)))
            Cells(i, j) = Left(Cells(i, j), InStr(1, Cell, Chr(10)) - 1)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

And

```
Sub LFtoRow()
Dim myWS As Worksheet, myRng As range
Dim LastRow As Long, iLoop As Long, jLoop As Long
Dim myString() As String

Set myWS = ActiveSheet
LastRow = myWS.Cells(myWS.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row

For iLoop = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    myString = Split(myWS.Cells(iLoop, 1), Chr(10))
    If UBound(myString, 1) > 0 Then
        myWS.Rows(iLoop + 1 & ":" & iLoop + UBound(myString, 1)).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
        For jLoop = 0 To UBound(myString, 1)
            myWS.Cells(iLoop + jLoop, 1) = myString(jLoop)
        Next jLoop
    End If
Next iLoop

End Sub
```

Either a new code entirely, or just something to add to the end would work. I have an example of what is happening, and what I would like it to look like below. (I know it shows column B in the photo, but at this point in the MACRO it is in column A)

What is happening:

[image]

What I need to happen:
[image]

Comment: Try `split` on line break? Not sure what syntax for that is though XD

Comment: Instead of doing a substitute for "   " you can use that string as OtherChar in your TextToColumns. That should save some code lines.

Comment: For the record, if this is a one-off task, you can split data on a new line delimiter with Text To Columns. You just need to (in the other delimiter text box) hold down `ALT` while you type `010`. 10 is the UNICODE value for a line feed aka Excel new line character.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff That does to columns. I need rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most likely is not the most concise way to do this, but this ended up working for me using @OldUgly's code.

```
Sub LFtoRow()
Dim myWS As Worksheet, myRng As range
Dim LastRow As Long, iLoop As Long, jLoop As Long
Dim myString() As String

Set myWS = ActiveSheet
LastRow = myWS.Cells(myWS.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row

For iLoop = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    myString = Split(myWS.Cells(iLoop, 1), Chr(10))
    If UBound(myString, 1) > 0 Then
        myWS.Rows(iLoop + 1 & ":" & iLoop + UBound(myString, 1)).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
        For jLoop = 0 To UBound(myString, 1)
            myWS.Cells(iLoop + jLoop, 1) = myString(jLoop)
        Next jLoop
    End If
Next iLoop

For iLoop = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    myString = Split(myWS.Cells(iLoop, 2), Chr(10))
    If UBound(myString, 1) > 0 Then
        For jLoop = 0 To UBound(myString, 1)
            myWS.Cells(iLoop + jLoop, 2) = myString(jLoop)
        Next jLoop
    End If
Next iLoop

For iLoop = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    myString = Split(myWS.Cells(iLoop, 3), Chr(10))
    If UBound(myString, 1) > 0 Then
        For jLoop = 0 To UBound(myString, 1)
            myWS.Cells(iLoop + jLoop, 3) = myString(jLoop)
        Next jLoop
    End If
Next iLoop

For iLoop = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    myString = Split(myWS.Cells(iLoop, 4), Chr(10))
    If UBound(myString, 1) > 0 Then
        For jLoop = 0 To UBound(myString, 1)
            myWS.Cells(iLoop + jLoop, 4) = myString(jLoop)
        Next jLoop
    End If
Next iLoop

For iLoop = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    myString = Split(myWS.Cells(iLoop, 5), Chr(10))
    If UBound(myString, 1) > 0 Then
        For jLoop = 0 To UBound(myString, 1)
            myWS.Cells(iLoop + jLoop, 5) = myString(jLoop)
        Next jLoop
    End If
Next iLoop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend code similar to the following to solve your problem. It has the following properties:

1. Uses the Split function to on Chr(10) to determine the strings you need on each line. Chr(10) is the linefeed character. Split generates an array of strings for you.
2. Inserts the correct number of rows for you.
3. Loops through your range from the bottom-up, so you process the complete range.

The code ...

```
Sub LFtoRow()
Dim myWS As Worksheet, myRng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, iLoop As Long, jLoop As Long
Dim myString() As String

Set myWS = Worksheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = myWS.Cells(myWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For iLoop = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    myString = Split(myWS.Cells(iLoop, 1), Chr(10))
    If UBound(myString, 1) > 0 Then
        myWS.Rows(iLoop + 1 & ":" & iLoop + UBound(myString, 1)).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
        For jLoop = 0 To UBound(myString, 1)
            myWS.Cells(iLoop + jLoop, 1) = myString(jLoop)
        Next jLoop
    End If
Next iLoop

End Sub
```

When presented with this input ...

[image]

... generates this result ...

[image]

Comment: is there a way to use this and check multiple columns? The one I have from you only splits column A I believe, and the other one is not splitting all of the cells either.

Comment: Certainly. However, the requirements aren't clear. 1) Do you want to check all columns with data? 2) What if two columns have a linefeed in the same row? Do you want to insert one row or two? 3) is there a need to keep specific row data together on the same row?

Comment: I apologize for not being specific enough. However, I do believe I got it to do what I need it to. In essence, I need it to check all columns that have data, if there is a linefeed in multiple columns in the same row, only insert one row and split all of the columns into that row. For your last question, I am not entirely certain what you mean, but it is pertinent that all data in one row stay in one row, which is why the linefeeds are causing me an issue in the first place if that makes sense.  I believe that answered your question.

Comment: I am sure there is a more concise way to do it, but I used the formula you provided and just used it to check each column, and for the columns passed the first column, don't insert a new row, but simply move the data down into the row below. Which, COULD lead to some complications, but I believe the way the export works, it should not create any issues. If you see the answer I provided using your code, it shows what I did exactly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion that should handle line breaks in all columns.

Also i removed the replacement that inserts a ";" and then splits on that. Complete code will be:

```
end_row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("a1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, OtherChar _
    :="   ", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

For i = 1 To end_row
    row_added = False
    For j = 1 To 4
        If InStr(1, Cell, Chr(10)) <> 0 Then
            If Not row_added Then
                Rows(i + 1).Insert
                row_added = True
                end_row = end_row + 1
            End If
            Cells(i + 1, j) = Right(Cells(i, j), Len(Cells(i, j)) - InStr(1, Cell, Chr(10)))
            Cells(i, j) = Left(Cells(i, j), InStr(1, Cell, Chr(10)) - 1)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Fredrik, I ended up using OldUgly's formula. It seemed to me as if you removed the ";" and then split on line break into columns? But then your code reads inserting rows, so I was simply confused. I did not test it, but I do appreciate your time on this!

Comment: @JRivs in your code you first did "=SUBSTITUTE(RC[-1],""   "", "";"")" into coulmn B. and then split based on ";". I insted directly split on ""   "" to save the extra steps of creating a new column, copying and pasting values and removing column A. The line break part is in the for loop. You can use just the loop.

Comment: @JRivs OldUgly's code only handles line breaks in column A. Mine looks thru all columns. Both work fine.

Comment: It is not working. I do not know if it happened when I tried to adjust it, or if it just was not working from the get go. It has been like partially working, but not entirely. Also, it is not splitting on the "   ", so I ended up having to re-insert my "replace with ;" code.